# Отладка на реальном устройстве (Nexus 7)

Tags: android, eclipse, эмулятор, android-adb

Люди, помогите пожалуйста. Уже не знаю что и делать. Установил Android SDK, все как полагается. Создаю первые приложения, код нормальный, компиляция ошибок не дает. Но тестировать это все дело на эмуляторе - "адский ад".

У меня есть Asus Nexus 7 (планшетик). Как мне на нем производить отладку? Eclipse и adb ну никак не видят его.

**p.s.** Да, я конечно же ввел планшет в режим "разработчика" и включил опцию "Отладка по USB"

**p.s.2.** Да, я вставляю USB в компьютер.

**p.s.3.** Дрова ставились с SDK Manager (также пробовал ставить с официального сайта ASUS)

**РЕШЕНИЕ**:
Абсолютно банальное: в планшете при подсоединении по USB, нужно выбрать режим камеры (**PTP**). Это странно, но это работает.

Не знаю с чем это связано, может быть это фича Andorid 4.2, может самого Asus Nexus 7. Но теперь все работает, всем огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `adb devices` выдаёт в списке устройсмтв ваш nexus?    

В `Run configurations -> ваша конфигурация -> Targets` проставьте manual, так Eclipse будет перед запуском предлагать выбрать девайс, на котором запускать приложение.    

И проверьте наличие драйвера usb для вашего устройства, если его нет - скачайте с сайта производителя и установите.

Comment: adb devices выдает пустой список. Дрова стоят, менял их, ставил драйвера от производителя, результат тот же. В Eclipse тоже с настройками возился. Но тут уже понятно, появится в adb devices, то заработает всё ))

Comment: При вставлении USB в компьютер, какой вид соединения выбираете?

Comment: "Подключен как устройство хранения данных" (MTP). Еще там есть PTP - Камера, чтобы передавать фото кажется.

Comment: в менеджере устройств случайно нет недоустановленных устройств? или с крестиком? после установки перезагружались?

Comment: @KoVadim Недоустановленных нет, и да, уже пробовал перезагружаться.

Comment: Только что установил на своем ноутбуке. Практически сразу завелось. Но странно то, что в диспетчере устройст определилось как самсунг Android composite ADB Interface. Но все работает.

Comment: Почисти все, что могло установить свои драйвера(всякие Сони, НТС). Конфликт явно какой-то есть. Потом уже можешь пробовать любой вариант по ссылке в моем ответе.

Comment: Надо сначала ставить дрова, а потом втыкать девайс. Дрова [лежат здесь](http://www.asus.com/Tablet_Mobile/Nexus_7/#support_Download_32)

Comment: Спасибо за советы, необходимо немного отвлечься. Обязательно отпишусь, как удастся что-нибудь сделать.

Comment: Host os не лишне указать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Установи на компьютер [PdaNet+](http://junefabrics.com/android/) и забудь про проблемы коннекта:)

Для минусующих: программа помогла в казалось бы безнадежной ситуации, когда Win 8 запрещает запускать программы с неподписанными драйверами, не уведомляя при этом владельца ОС - меня.

Поэтому нужно закрыть все, вытащить девайс, установить PdaNet, воткнуть обратно девайс(должна появится в трее табличка "Девайс подключен") и снова запустить эклипс и после запускать проект - должен появится девайс в списке.

**UPD**
Думаю для корректной работы PdaNet ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО установить на компьютер HTC Sync. Каким-то боком он работает с данным ПО. Выявлено опытным путем при подключении девайса к интернету на компьютере.

А если не помогает, то возможные варианты: [Nexus 7 not visible over usb via “adb devices” from Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64).

Comment: Установил, только не понял как ей пользоваться именно в моем случае.

Comment: 1) зачем минусовать если ты не понимаешь, что тебе предлагают? 2) тебе нужна отладка на девайсе? установи PdaNet - запусти проект в эклипс, там увидишь свой планшет в списке. Эта программа помогает в таких случаях, когда все плохо и adb не видит твое устройство. Еще вопросы?

Comment: Лично я ничего не минусовал. Если люди хоть как-то пытаются мне помочь, таких вещей не делаю, и вообще ставить минусы - это не моё.

Comment: Так или иначе - эта программа - то что тебе нужно. Просто поставь как надо ее, запусти клипс и посмотри результат.

Comment: Не помогает, пишет ошибку при соединении: HTC Sync error = -1
И не понятно причем тут HTC.

Comment: Удали все драйвера, соединялки, программы синхронизации(HTC Sync именно она). Попробуй поставить PdaNet снова. Вообще странно. Сколько устройств не подключал PdaNet со всеми справляется стабильно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Еще есть Sony Erricson Xperia Ray. Подсоединял к компу, установлены все дрова (родные). Но с ним такая же проблема. Может тут правда замешан как-то HTC Sync, но я искал и ничего подобного не нашел (

Answer (score 1):

РЕШЕНИЕ: Абсолютно банальное: в планшете при подсоединении по USB, нужно выбрать режим камеры (PTP). Это странно, но это работает.
Спасибо огромное! У меня тоже сработало !!!  До этого переставил кучу программ, ничего не работало.

Comment: рад, что пригодилось)

Answer (score 0):

А если не срабатывает ни как медиа-устройство (МТР), ни как камера (РТР)? Пытаюсь подключиться через 7-дата-андроид-рекавери. Драйвера для юсб скачал с официального сайта асус. Отладку включил. Кабель подключл. Пишет, что не видит никаких андроид устройств и советует вкл. "отладку по юсб" и подсоединить кабель. Или лыжи не едут, или я ... что-то не так делаю.

Правда у меня FonePad 7 (модель K00E), но в подключении к компу по юсб думаю разницы особой нет.

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо DroidAlex - мне помогла программа PdaNet+, а решение с переключением на режим камеры наоборот ничего не дало.

DroidAlex

> Почисти все, что могло установить свои драйвера(всякие Сони, НТС).
>   Конфликт явно какой-то есть. Потом уже можешь пробовать любой вариант
>   по ссылке в моем ответе.

Comment: Старайтесь давать более развернутые ответы, или оставляйте комментарий вместо ответа!