# Отладка на реальном устройстве (Nexus 7)

Tags: android

Люди, помогите пожалуйста. Уже не знаю что и делать.Установил Android SDK, все как полагается. Создаю первые приложения, код нормальный, компиляция ошибок не дает. Но тестировать это все дело на эмуляторе - "адский ад".

У меня есть Asus Nexus 7 (планшетик). Как мне на нем производить отладку? Eclipse и adb ну никак не видят его.

**p.s.** Да, я конечно же ввел планшет в режим "разработчика" и включил опцию "Отладка по USB"**p.s.2.** Да, я вставляю USB в компьютер.**p.s.3.** Дрова ставились с SDK Manager (также пробовал ставить с официального сайта ASUS)

Comment: Тоже маюсь автору +, тоже интересует

Comment: Debugging from Eclipse with ADT ?

Comment: Как это понять? Если все правильно понимаю, то да, с ADT. Потому, что в заголовке Eclipse в конце стоит ADT.

Comment: Это плагин, и че с ним неа? Мой сосед с права отлаживает именно так, а сосед с лева в IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: А ну да, ADT присутствует однозначно. Потому, что этот пакет Eclipse шел вместе с  Andorid SDK в комплекте с сайта разработки Andoird (Google inc.)

Comment: И с этим плагином не находит устройство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решена на hashcode.ru, вот [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/190372/android-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-nexus-7)Также цитирую решение оттуда:РЕШЕНИЕ: Абсолютно банальное: в планшете при подсоединении по USB, нужно выбрать режим камеры (PTP). Это странно, но это работает.Не знаю с чем это связано, может быть это фича Andorid 4.2, может самого Asus Nexus 7. Но теперь все работает, всем огромное спасибо за помощь.